# Highcharts error when using ES6

Tags: highcharts, ecmascript-6

I am importing Highcharts and Highchart more in the following way:

```
import highcharts from 'highcharts';
import highchartsMore from 'highcharts-more';
highchartsMore(highcharts);
```

After the graph loads I get the following error:

`Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN".`

Note:
not critical, yet annoying.

Comment: The question lacks [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't think it is possible to figure out what's wrong. What did make you think that the problem is ES6?

Comment: Ok, I will add a fiddle a bit later. thanks

Comment: I think it is ES6 since when using ES5 it did not happen :)

Comment: What is your bundler/module loader?

Comment: Webpack + babel